# Hiding jobs from an Allure Report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cicd

I have a Jenkins pipeline with jobs that execute several tests (I use Java with Selenium and TestNG).

At the end of the pipeline I have a job that generates the Allure Report which is working fine. However I want to exclude certain jobs from appearing in the report because they are not actual tests. For instance the job that creates the Allure Report appears even though it's not really related.

The runner file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Allure Report">
    <test name="Allure">
        <classes>
            <class name="util.buildreport.AllureReportTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Is there a configuration I'm missing on a Jenkins level or can I exclude the job directly from the Java project?